# what is the best way to unpack a FIX message into a python dictionary?

Tags: python

string looks like this:

```
input = 'key1=val1\001key2=val2\001key3=val3\001key4=val4'
```

where \001 is the separator

```
message = {}
```

uh... now what? I know I can do something like

```
my_list = imput.split('\001')
my_dict = {}

for pair in my_list:
    tup = pair.split('=')
    my_dict[tup[0]] = tup[1]
```

This works but it seems really ugly. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you like this:

```
>>> dict(p.split('=') for p in input.split('\001'))
{'key3': 'val3', 'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1', 'key4': 'val4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this:

```
import re
fixMsg = 'key1=val1\001key2=val2\001key3=val3\001key4=val4'
d = dict(re.findall("(.*?)=(.*?)\001", fixMsg+'\001'))
```